# What happens if reassigning a variable in class definitions is allowed just like in main method and in a normal method in JAVA

Tags: java

Please go through this code and explain why the compiler is giving an error at LINE 11 in class definition. But the same way is allowed for local variables in a method. please give an example that tells what happens if that int a; a=10; and  int b=10;b=20; like statements are allowed in class definitions. I'm interested to know the reasons behind it.Provide the answer with a real time class definition.

```
public class Demo {
// taking 4 instance variables a, b,c ,d
int c, d;

/*
* doesn't need to initialized with a value before use since it will be
* initialized with "0" by default.We can also initialize a variable with a
* different value
*/

int a;//compile time error // LINE 11
a=10;

int b=10;
// reassigning a value to variaible b 
b=20;//compile time error

void method() {

// printing value of instance variable d which is not initialized
System.out.println(d);

int i;// local variable
i = 10;// must be initialized with a value before use 
System.out.println(i);

c = 10; // initializing instance variable c in a method
System.out.println(c);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

int l; // local variable
l = 10; // no error
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a class is only allowed to contain statements, only member definitions.
You should inline your initialization:

```
public class Demo {
    // taking 4 instance variables a, b,c ,d
    int c, d;

    int a = 10;

    int b=20; // redundant to initialize with 10 and the reinitialize

    //... rest of the class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a; // here you define (default value =0) an instance level variable.
a=10; // error : because you have already defined "a", you cannot redefine it inside the same class. Classes are used only to define the structure, not modify the values.

int b=10; //No error : You are  defining it only once. and not changing the value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can Initialize using non-static blocks

```
public class Demo {

    int c, d;

    int a ;
    //non static block
    {
        a=10;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't do assignment outside of method. You are not calling a method method() thatsy you are getting error.